# Is possible return a query like Excel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I wonder if in MySQL is possible take a report like this image:

[image: report]

**Produtos**   = Products

**Fornecedor** = Supplier

It's for a system PHP of quotation of products. The supllier participates of quotation typing values for each products of quotation.

I need to develop a query to return results like the image. It's possible? Or I have to develop this in my application?

My database
[image: database]

Comment: Not in MySQL alone, because MySQL doesn't do formatting... it only holds the data; but if you return the right data from MySQL to a PHP script, you can use that to format it for output in your report. However, while there are libraries that can help you do this, you'll still have to do some work yourself. If you want to create an Excel file, look at the PHPExcel library ( http://phpexcel.codeplex.com )

Comment: @Mark you should make this an answer!

Answer (score 0):

To just get the representation like above, take a look at the section 'Pivot tables (crosstabs)' here: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/mysqlquerytree.php

In Your case I would suggest to create a view across the tables you want to query (using `JOIN`) and create a ODBC connection to Excel.

That way you can analyse the Data in Excel, in a Pivot table and what have you.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, MySQL doesn't do formatting. The closest you can get is to generate a CSV and then opening in Excel. Excel, AFAIK, can open CSV files without conversion issues. A query would look like:

```
SELECT col1,col2 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv' 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM table;
```